# programatically Changing uiwebview frame which was created using nib

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIwebview created using nib. I have many controllers accessing this webview(in nib) . For each call from different controllers the size of webview in nib should be changed accordingly.How to implement this programatically?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If i implement this then i receive an error stating that property frame cannot be found in a forward class object 'CALayer'

Answer (score 1):

You need only create outlet of this UIWebView in your controller.(and property)

```
IBOutlet UIWebview *webExample;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebview *webExample;
```

When in your code send a call to the UIViewWeb you can detect de sender and change the view's frame size.

```
webExample.layer.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,200,200);
```